# How to implement list of checkable buttons with pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, tabs

I want to implement list of radiobuttons, but radiobutton shouldn't have a circle and if radiobutton is checked, then the background color is different from the others.
Like in this photo.
[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsOeE.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsOeE.png)

I think I can use radiobuttons or tabs, but i don't know how to change the styles of this things. Tell me a widget with similar logic or how to change the style of radiobuttons/tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the circle of a radio button, then you probably don't need a radio button at all.

Instead, use standard QPushButtons (or QToolButtons) with [`setCheckable(True)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#checkable-prop) and add them to a [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html).

```py
win = QWidget()
win.setStyleSheet('''
    QPushButton[checkable="true"]::checked {
        background: red;
    }
''')
layout = QHBoxLayout(win)
group = QButtonGroup()
for title in 'cdefgh':
    button = QPushButton(title)
    layout.addWidget(button)
    button.setCheckable(True)
    group.addButton(button)
group.buttons()[0].setChecked(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

i set css rule:

```
css = '''
QRadioButton::indicator {
  image: none;
}
QRadioButton::checked
{
  background-color : red;   
}
'''
radioButton.setStyleSheet(css)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).